# ArcGIS polyline file How to update column in attribute table

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I have three columns

Before update

```
from node    to node    gridcode   
2            3          8
3            2          9
7            2          5
```

After update, I want "node column" to be same as "grid code" column, so I used field calculator in ArcGIS (from node = gridcode). My "from node" column has been changed to gridcode but not sure how to update "to node" column (that depends on values in “from node” column)

Below is the final result I want:

```
from node    to node    gridcode
8            9          8
9            8          9
5            8          5
```

So far I have tried "join", "spatial join" but I am not getting the required results. How can I do that in Python or ArcGIS?

Comment: What's the relationship between "from node" and "to node"? Without knowing that, it's going to be impossible to answer.

Comment: @Erica  This data is  for streams/rivers from node (river starting point or upstream), to node(where river is draining or next stream downstream). I delineated my watershed based on digital elevation map and I got my stream network in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this I can see is with Python.

First you need to build a dictionary to understand what the relationship is between the old node values and new node values -- `old_node` and `new_node`. This can be done with a [SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm), matching up the "from node" (`old_node`) to the gridcode (`new_node`).

```
# instantiate empty dictionary
node_values = {}
# build dictionary of values
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class, ["fromnode", "gridcode"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        old_node = row[0]
        new_node= row[1]
        node_values[old_node] = new_node
```

Then, you need to update all your values. This needs an [UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) (somewhat like Field Calculator, but lets you do more since you're working within Python).

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, ["fromnode", "tonode", "gridcode"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # set fromnode to gridcode value
        row[0] = row[2]
        # set tonode to new equivalent node
        to_node = row[1]
        new_to_node = node_values[to_node]
        row[1] = new_to_node
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---

Note that there are a lot of ways this code can be "tightened up", improved, and shortened, and there are variables that need to be assigned (e.g. `feature_class`) before those snippets will work properly. As always, I recommend making a backup of your data before messing around in it with somebody else's Python scripts ;)